# How to programmatically call a Maven-task

Tags: java, clojure, maven-2, classpath

I'm using Maven in the context of another build-tool (leiningen for Clojure, but this should not matter), and I would like to know how I would call a plugin like [dependency:build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) programmatically (i.e. via the Maven-API, not via the `mvn`-command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See how org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase from maven-plugin-testing-harness is implemented. Here's a code snippet from some of my tests which may be helpful.

```
public abstract class JAXBGenerateTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    static {
        System.setProperty("basedir", getBaseDir().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    protected MavenProjectBuilder mavenProjectBuilder;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        mavenProjectBuilder = (MavenProjectBuilder) getContainer().lookup(
                MavenProjectBuilder.ROLE);
    }

    protected static File getBaseDir() {...}

    /**
     * Validate the generation of a java files from purchaseorder.xsd.
     * 
     * @throws MojoExecutionException
     */
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {

        final File pom = new File(getBaseDir(),
        "src/test/resources/test-pom.xml");

        final ArtifactRepository localRepository = new DefaultArtifactRepository( "local", 

                new File(getBaseDir(), "target/test-repository").toURI().toURL().toString()             , new DefaultRepositoryLayout());


        final MavenProject mavenProject = mavenProjectBuilder.build(pom, localRepository, null);


        final XJC2Mojo generator = (XJC2Mojo) lookupMojo("generate", pom);
        generator.setProject(mavenProject);
        generator.setLocalRepository(localRepository);
        generator.setSchemaDirectory(new File(getBaseDir(),"src/test/resources/"));
        generator.setSchemaIncludes(new String[] { "*.xsd" });
        generator.setBindingIncludes(new String[] { "*.xjb" });
        generator.setGenerateDirectory(new File(getBaseDir(), "target/test/generated-sources"));
        generator.setVerbose(true);
        generator.setGeneratePackage("unittest");
        generator.setRemoveOldOutput(false);

        generator.execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25):

Use the [Maven Invoker API](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html). Its quick and easy.

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile( new File( "/path/to/pom.xml" ) );
request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "install" ) );

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setMavenHome(new File("/usr"));

try
{
  invoker.execute( request );
}
catch (MavenInvocationException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's forking a new lifecycle. TFQ is trying to invoke a mojo within the current lifecycle.

Comment: and if i want execute a plugin and one of its executions by id ?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a better solution: use the [Mojo-Executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) library. It exposes a simple Java API for invoking Maven plugins.

Comment: this just replaces the need to execute a Maven Plugin with the need to execute another Maven Plugin.

Comment: @JensSchauder: No, it doesn't. Mojo-Executor provides a simple Java API that invokes Maven plugins on your behalf. Invoking Maven plugins directly requires a lot of heavy lifting!

Comment: @JensSchauder: Don't forget to +1 my answer in case you voted it down before. Thanks.

Comment: Hi can you provide a clear example of how to invoke a plugin from a piece of source code that is not a a plugin ? Or put it more simply how does one use your API to invoke plugins declared in a pom file without writing another plugin ?

Comment: @devlearn, I'm not sure I understand your question. What is "a piece of source code that is not a plugin"? In Maven you can either invoke plugins from the POM (XML) or a plugin (Java). Are you trying to invoke a plugin from a POJO outside of Maven?

Comment: Yes precisely, I was trying to invoke maven from a test class in order to get the inherited properties. I ended up by using the properties plugin to dump the props them then read it from my test class. It is much easier that way, and also much faster then using the invoker.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ant Maven tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) can give you an idea how to do it ([DependenciesTask source](https://maven.apache.org/components/ant-tasks-archives/ant-tasks-2.1.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/DependenciesTask.html)). Another route may be the [PomModuleDescriptorParser](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/parser/m2/PomModuleDescriptorParser.java) used by [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).