# executable jar for selenium testng maven project which dont have a main class

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a Selenium TestNG project created with maven.  ``

- There is no main class for this prject
- Using TestNg.xml file and the same is configured in pom.xml file.
- Ran 'maven test' from eclispe and the test runs successfully based on the classes defined in testng.xml. no issues here
- Tried the same from command prompt  using `mvn test` from the project folder and it ran succesfully. no issues here too.

My requirement : Now i want to package this project either to executable jar or are there are any option to make a executable file so that i can schedule the run using a batch file.

To do this I ran the 'mvn package' command and it generated the jar file in the target folder. Now when i try to run this as `java -jar myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` i get the message as "no main manifest attribute, in myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar". This is expected behavior since there is no  main class in my case.
 So i created a main class with just one line to print "text" and added the  mainClass below entry in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
    <manifest>
        <mainClass>mainPackage.MainOne</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
</configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Then i ran mvn package and it generated the new jar. 
Then went to target folder of my project and ran the command as `java -jar myProj.jar mainPackage.MainOne`, it ran and just printed "text". MY TestNG tests did not run. It just ran main class :(.. 
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know that i have found a solution as provided in this [How to programmatically call a Maven-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146580/how-to-programmatically-call-a-maven-task)

as i mentioned I did use the main class. So i did the below

-Added the maven-invoker dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- Updated my main class class as below using this link- http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html

  ```
  public class MainOne {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
          request.setPomFile( new File( "pom.xml" ));
          request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "install" ));
          Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
          invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));
          try {
              invoker.execute( request );
          } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 
      } 
  }
  ```
- Then from command prompt ran the command `mvn clean package shade:shade`
- This created the jar in the target folder.
- Copied the jar into Project folder and ran the command `java -jar myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, my tests starting running perfectly!!.

Comment: I have followed all of your instructions above but I keep getting: $ java -jar myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
no main manifest attribute, in myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with JUnit. I run my tests programmatically from main method. I don't know TestNG but you can look here how to do this - [Running TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)